# Don't break inside a function declaration for operator overloading

Tags: c++, clang-format

I want

```cpp
constexpr result_type operator*() const
{
    // ...
}
```

But it will be formatted to

```cpp
constexpr result_type
    operator*() const
{
    // ...
}
```

This issue also happens on `operator[]` and member `operator==`, but non-member (`friend`) `operator==` won't be break into two lines.

Edit: Tried to set `PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine` to a large value but didn't work.

My `.clang-format` file is based on LLVM style with following line break settings

```
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel: true
  AfterClass: true
  AfterStruct: true
  AfterEnum: true
  AfterUnion: true
  AfterControlStatement: Always
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch: true
  BeforeElse: true
  BeforeLambdaBody: true
  BeforeWhile: false
  IndentBraces: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false

AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes

BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: Always
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakInheritanceList: AfterColon
BreakStringLiterals: false
BreakAfterAttributes: Leave
```

Comment: Have you read this documentation? https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html. It might be : AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine or your maximum line length is just very short

Comment: @PepijnKramer `AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine ` is already set to `true`, and my column limit is set to 0.